# Is there a way make a parameter of a function be put in quotes in one life of code and not the other?

Tags: r, function, object, paste

I'm not showing my actual code because it has many running parts, so let me just showcase what I am running into. I have this function:

```
paste <- function(d) {
        print(paste0(d,"_test", sep =""))
}
```

What I wanted returned would be if I did `paste(advising)` for example is "advising_test".

The reason I am not just doing `paste("advising")` is because in the function I am writing, advising needs to be used as both in quotes in order to name a particular object and needs to be used as the name of a dataframe that I am doing another function on. Therefore, I need to figure out how in the code I can paste the parameter with quotes, so I can use the term both ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
paste <- function(d) {
        print(paste0(ensym(d),"_test", sep =""))
}
```

Edit : You can have a look at https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/nse-defuse.html

Answer (score 1):

Use `substitute` .  No packages are used.

```
mypaste <- function(d) print(paste0(substitute(d), "_test"))

# test
mypaste(advising)
## [1] "advising_test"
```